# ASP.NET vNext global config access

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

What is the correct/recommended way of accessing the `config.json` file (or wherever else config is stored) in ASP.NET vNext?

In the `Startup` class, I set up the config like so:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
}
```

But then if I need to access the connection string elsewhere, how do I do it? For example, in the `OnConfiguring` of an EF context, how do I get the connection string:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(EntityOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer( ??? );
```

I've read that you could use this:

```
var config = Startup.Configuration
    ?? new Configuration()
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

But (a) Startup is not static and (b) you surely don't want to go rebuilding the configuration setup every time you need it - that's duplicating code everywhere it's used.

I've also read that you should use [Dependency Injection](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/25), but that link doesn't fully show you how to do it. If my DbContext constructor has an injected parameter, then how do I inject that into a parameterless BaseApiController?

This really seems like a common/simple requirement: After the configuration in Startup, how to I access that configuration elsewhere? This should in documentation/examples everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've got that's working:

### Startup

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
        // create & store the configuration once
        var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        // adding/registering the dbContext for dependency injection as a singleton
        services.AddSingleton(s => new Context(Configuration));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "default",
                  template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
}
```

### DbContext

```
public sealed class Context : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    public Context(IConfiguration config)
    {
        // store the injected config
        _config = config;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ForSqlServer().UseIdentity();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(EntityOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        // use the injected config
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"));

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    private readonly Context _context;

    // have the context injected
    public TestController(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        return new ObjectResult(_context.Clients.ToList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, you should avoid registering your database context as a singleton. Also passing around the raw `IConfiguration` interface isn't a good practice.

In stead could create a POCO options class:

```
public class DbOptions
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set }
}
```

And populate it in the `ConfigureServices` method using the section in the config.json:

```
services.Configure<DbOptions>(Configuration.GetConfigurationSection("Data:DefaultConnection"));
```

Then you can inject it into your `DbContext` (and in controllers, etc.):

```
public sealed class Context : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    private readonly DbOptions _options;

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    public Context(IOptions<DbOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        // store the injected options
        _options = optionsAccessor.Options;
    }

    // other code..
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Here's a really good article I've just found: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jun/03/Strongly-typed-AppSettings-Configuration-in-ASPNET-5

Comment: One downside: I was using a BaseApiController that instantiated & disposed the context, and all controllers inherited from that. Now I can't use that pattern, as the BaseApiController needs a parameterless constructor. You know how to get around that?

Comment: That's basically what I explained. The `Configuration` class used in that post is a bit outdated though. You have to use `ConfigurationBuilder` now and call `Build`.