# vNext ConfigurationModel null reference-ing when picking up a config.json?

Tags: asp.net-core

```
using Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel;
---

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var config = new Configuration();
    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    config.AddJsonFile("config.json");
}
```

Using the above, with the config.json placed in the [root directory](http://i.kfwls.co/JGNw) under the project name, I get a null reference exception?

[image]

This is practically a brand new/empty solution, I've never had this issue before.

I've tried empty files, no file, the default generated contents, different file extension, all give the same error, leading me to think that it is looking outside what should be the root dir.

However, it also does the same when supplied with a direct filepath...

It also doesn't fail when adding env variables on the line above, so it's not likely to be an issue with the `Configuration` object itself.

Same behaviour across both dnx core/coreclr and full.

Comment: Which beta are you using?

Comment: Beta4 for confmodel + confmodel.json, 6 for EF, 5 for the rest (http://i.kfwls.co/JGOm)

Comment: Don't mix betas, use beta6 for everything. That will probably solve your issue.

Comment: Try using `beta6` with `ConfigurationBuilder` and `app.ApplicationBasePath`, like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044013/asp-net-vnext-global-config-access

Comment: Is `beta6` out for configurationModel? I can't pull it from nuget, only 4. Dropping down to 4 for everything does seem to have fixed the problem though, but not ideal

Comment: So was `Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel` with the `= new Configuration();` way of doing it replaced by `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration` and using a`ConfigurationBuilder` in later betas? The former only going up to `beta4`, with the latter appearing in `5/6`

Comment: tl;dr, yes https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/25 Dammit guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out `Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel` from `beta4` was renamed to `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration` in `beta 5/6`

with the `= new Configuration` method being replaced with having to use a `ConfigurationBuilder`, specifying the app path with `appEnv.ApplicationBasePath` in it's constructor.

`= new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)`

See: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/25