# Can't Read Setting out of JSON file in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my **Startup.cs** file I have the following:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Set up configuration sources.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    var fooValue = Configuration.Get("foo");
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

And in my **appsettings.json** file I have  `{ "foo":  "bar" }`

Later in my Startup class I have:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    var fooValue = Configuration.Get("foo");
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

I try to watch to value of fooValue change in my Locals debugger by setting a breakpoint on it (VS2015 with the ASP.NET 5 extensions) but I get the following error when I step over it:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor.

I'm following the [MVA **Configuring Data** at 18m 53s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/?l=8eIeQ5pXB_3201937557)

I've tried creating a config.json file as in the example, but the template seems to have changed, and it doesn't help anyway.

Should I be allowed to grab configuration info out of .json files like this?

Comment: Here's a similar question with a working example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32044957/390421  (Which includes loading json data and accessing it through a config.Get() call.)

Comment: Additionally, you can find more examples on how to access nested json properties here: http://whereslou.com/2014/05/23/asp-net-vnext-moving-parts-iconfiguration/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to have a full answer here. You were doing everything right, but the overload of *CongigurationBinder.Get* you chose expects configuration section name instead of a key.

```
public static T Get<T>(this IConfiguration configuration, T defaultValue)
```

But there is a different overload you can use:

```
public static T Get<T>(this IConfiguration configuration, string key)
```

So your code should look like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
    var fooValue = Configuration.Get<string>("foo");
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

I think the documentation is not so clear yet, so I mostly using reflector or GitHub source code to find out what the API is actually doing. Here is a link to the [public repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration) for that package.

Comment: Thank you. A long term goal for me has to be how to better understand the public examples out there.

Answer (score 2):

To answer to your question: **yes you can**  grab the configuration out of .json files, just change

```
Configuration.Get("foo");
```

to:

```
Configuration.Get<string>("foo");
```

and you will be able to read it.